# How to calculate the Max Buy and max sell of an erc20 token even without liquidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereum-classic, forks

How to calculate the Max Buy and max sell of an erc20 token even without liquidity.

There are many Ethereum tokens with a limit to the maximum amount of tokens that can be bought at once and sold.

I tried to simulate this by using callStatic and trying to see how much amount I can buy at once through Uniswap router until I hit a transfer failed.

But this works only if there's liquidity added to the token on Uniswap and trade is open.

I see some telegram bots that are able to extract the Max buy and max sell of any token even without liquidity.

Are there any suggestions on how the same can be achieved in the most accurate way possible?